# devDependencies not installing

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to run an existing React app but I'm getting the following error every time I perform `npm install`:

[image: npm error]

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.8",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.36",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "apexcharts": "^3.34.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "chartjs-react": "^3.4.0",
    "country-state-city": "^3.0.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "detect-browser": "^5.3.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "history": "^5.1.0",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.48",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.21",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.23.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-saga-retry": "^0.1.0",
    "reselect": "^4.1.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tailwind-scrollbar": "^1.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "zipcodes": "^8.0.0"
  },
```

I'm using Node.js version 16.15.0, NPM version 8.8.0 and Tailwind version 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the installation of npm module, so it will install them, even if they don't respect some constraints:

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: thank you but it didn't work. I also tried adding --legacy-peer-deps but I got a dependency tree error and when i resolve it, it goes back to the error above